# expected struct `String` found struct `Vec<&String>`

Tags: rust

I have a function to reverse characters in words and I need to know how to convert a Vec<&String> into a regular owned String (with spaces between the words).

```
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
let mut split = words.split_whitespace();
let vec: Vec<&str> = split.collect();
let vec2 = vec!();
    for word in vec {
        vec2.push(&word.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
    }
    return vec2;
}
```

.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:8:12
  |
1 | fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
  |                                  ------ expected `String` because of return type
...
8 |     return vec2;
  |            ^^^^ expected struct `String`, found struct `Vec`
  |
  = note: expected struct `String`
             found struct `Vec<&String>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `challenge` due to previous error


NOTE: Line numbers in error messages can be incorrect due to concatenation.
```

Comment: Error is pretty clear: You are trying to return a whole `Vec<String>` (`vec2`) when the return type is *one* `String`. Do you mean to [`join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) then back together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of your code with minimal changes to make it work. You basically only need to add a `.join(' ')` to your last statement:

```rust
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
    let split = words.split_whitespace();
    let vec: Vec<&str> = split.collect();
    let mut vec2 = vec![];
    for word in vec {
        vec2.push(word.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
    }
    vec2.join(" ")
}


fn main() {
    let sentence = "hello world";
    
    assert_eq!(reverse_words(sentence), "olleh dlrow");
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=518d6071b070b9466d9074675b9ae346)

This is an inefficient implementation requiring a lot of allocation though. You can chain methods of the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#) trait to get a solution that does not require as much allocation:

```rust
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
    words
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|w| w.chars().rev().chain([' ']))
        .flatten()
        .take(words.len())
        .collect::<String>()
}

fn main() {
    let sentence = "hello world";

    assert_eq!(reverse_words(sentence), "olleh dlrow");
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1bcf7215769e0fc122b3fa3830e91968)

Comment: nit: instead of writing tests in a `main` function you could have added `#[test]` and made them proper tests with a descriptive name.