# How to transfer ownership outside of a Rust loop while iterating over a vec of &str?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I've been solving a simple codewars kata, the one where you know the answer immediately, and yet, 1.5 hours in, the borrow-checker in Rust is still defeating me --.-- Hence, I'm here to ask yet another question about ownership :)

Let's say the task is *"Given a `&str` of words, return a String where each word is reversed, preserving the word order"*.

The naïve answer is straightforward enough: 1) split your string, 2) iterate over words, 3) reverse each word, 4) join the reversed words.

But when I do something like this:

```
fn sentence_reverse(words: &str) -> String {
    let v:Vec<&str> = vec!();
    
    for w in words.split_whitespace() {
        v.push(&w.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
    }
    
    v.join(" ")
}
```

...I encounter a world of hurt.

Basically, having tried out several variations (iterating over `.split()` directly, shadowing the initial string as mutable `let mut words:Vec<&str> = words.split().collect()` and iterating over it via indexes and assigning the result in place), I still encounter the same issue: the result of `w.chars().rev().collect()` lives only within the scope of the `for` loop, because it yields a `&str`, so when I try to `v.join(" ")` later, the borrow-checker won't let me do it (and for a good reason, I'm sure).

Before you tell me "Just `.map()` it!" – yes, of course I did `.map()` it in the end. The point of the question is to understand, how does `.map()` handle it, how do you get a `vec` of `&str` inside an inner scope and successfully transfer it to the outer one.

Sorry for a wall of text, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499155/20665825. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497758/expected-struct-string-found-struct-vecstring describes the exact same problem you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't compile is that you're creating a `String` inside the loop, and storing a reference to it in `v`. You cannot store a reference to the `String` allocated inside the loop into a variable in the outer scope as the `String` is dropped at the end of each iteration. You can instead store the `String` in a `Vec<String>` and your function compiles:

```rust
fn sentence_reverse(words: &str) -> String {
    let mut v: Vec<String> = vec![];

    for w in words.split_whitespace() {
        v.push(w.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
    }

    v.join(" ")
}
```